# Large number of columns in Django

Tags: django, sqlite

I have performance data for a model execution instance that I am trying to store in Django (sqlite backend). There are 435 timers with 11 different attributes per timer resulting in 4,785 unique values that need to be stored per run. I wrote code that generated the models.py code. It gets 1,564 columns in and throws the below error. There are no duplicate columns of that name as I have checked the models.py file. When I switch that line with the next in the models file (and make a new migration) it dies at the same line number but new column name.

First time through:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: duplicate column name: CAM_export_processes
```

Second time:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: duplicate column name: CAM_export_threads
```

What limitation am I hitting here?

Comment: Is this a ForeignKey field, or just a regular data field?

Comment: One ForeignKey, the rest are a mix of Integer, Decimal and Char(100)

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518346/getting-duplicate-column-name-error-in-django-for-no-apparent-reason

Comment: That looks like a case where they are trying to setup a ForeignKey to the same table (class Location, and key on Location) and why the 'self' keyword helps them.
I have a cases class and a case_timers class. I am trying to reference cases from case_timers:
class cases(models.Model):
...


class case_timers(models.Model):
  case                          = models.ForeignKey(cases)
  DRIVER_INIT_processes                 = models.IntegerField()
  DRIVER_INIT_threads           = models.IntegerField()
  DRIVER_INIT_count                     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

Comment: try a faked migration, then comment out those fields, makemigrations/migrate and then add the fields again and makemigrations/migrate

Answer (score 0):

> **The default setting for SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN is 2000.**

This comes from the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html). If you are storing over 1000 columns in a table you are most definitely *doing something wrong <sup>(tm)</sup>*.

While your math is probably sound, there is a chance django is throwing in some extra columns for its own metadata which is pushing you closer to (or over) the limit.

Seriously reconsider your approach for storing this data.